# Getting List of Objects by a type given by a string

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, types

I get objects by

```
IEnumerable<ObjectStateEntry> om = context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(System.Data.EntityState.Modified);
```

How can I get a `List` of the objects with a type given by a string?

```
Type typ = Type.GetType("mytype");
var om2 = om.Select(s => s.Entity).OfType<typ>(); // does not work
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are trying to do cannot be done statically: `var` corresponds to the *static* type of the expression, while the type of your expression on the right is clearly non-static (it's `IEnumerable<T>`, where `T` is not known before the runtime).

This, however, is legal:

```
var om2 = om.Select(s => s.Entity).Where(v => typ.IsInstanceOfType(v));
```

This would produce an `IEnumerable<ObjectStateEntry>`.

Comment: Note, this will return exact matches and matches where the item is a base class of 'typ'.

Comment: @JustinHarvey Right, that is the same thing the `OfType<T>` does.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
Type typ = Type.GetType("mytype");
var om2 = om.Select(s => s.Entity).Where(e=>typeof(e) == typ);
```

Note that his will return matches where the types are exact matches (as opposed to being in the same inheritance tree).